# Why does async/await break on server call?

Tags: angular, typescript, asynchronous, async-await

I am trying to implement async/await with server call. However, the `async` function doesn't wait for the `await`ed function to get resolved. Below is the code i have written.

**index.ts**

```
async verifyOtp(){
    this.invalidOtpLength=false;
    this.invalidOtp=false;
    if(this.otp.length < 6){
      this.invalidOtpLength=true;
    }else if(this.otp.length==6 && this.otp !=this.otpFromServer){
      this.invalidOtp=true;
      this.invalidOtpLength=false;

      //decrease the no of attempts by 1
      if(this.otpAttemptsRemaining>1){this.otpAttemptsRemaining-=1}
        else{document.getElementById('otpMaxAttemptsPopupButton').click()}
    }else{
      console.log("Before promise")
      await this.getDetailsForPanAndAadhaar();
      console.log("After promise")
      this.wizard.navigation.goToNextStep();
      console.log("Aadhar values: ", this.aadharValues);
      console.log("PAN values: ", this.panValues);
    }
  }


getDetailsForPanAndAadhaar(){
    return new Promise((resolve) =>{
      let obj={};
      obj['serviceName']='ePanDetlService'
      obj['aadhaarNum']=this.aadharNumber.value.replace(/\s/g, '');
      obj['uidaiDetailsFlag']='Y';
      obj['otp']=this.otp;
      this.http.put('http://localhost:8080/servicesapi/updateEntity', obj).subscribe((data) =>{
          console.log("Initial data ", data);
          let aadharRegex=new RegExp(/^aadhaar./);
          let panRegex=new RegExp(/^pan./);
          delete data['header'];
          delete data['messages'];
          console.log("New data: ", data);
          for(let key in data){
            if(key.match(aadharRegex)){
              this.aadharValues[key]=data[key];
            }else if(key.match(panRegex)){
              this.panValues[key]=data[key];
            }
          }
        })
        resolve(null);
    })
  }
```

In the above code when the `getDetailsForPanAndAadhaar()` function is implemented as it is, in the console, the statements `Before Promise` and `After Promise` are displayed before the promise gets resolved (the `data` is consoled after the two statements).

However, on changing the implementation of `getDetailsForPanAndAadhaar()` as below, the code works fine.

**changed getDetailsForPanAndAadhaar()**

```
getDetailsForPanAndAadhaar(){
  return new Promise((resolve) =>{
    setTimeout(() =>{
      console.log("Inside promise")
      resolve("High Time....");
    }, 5000);
})
```

I also tried changing the resolve statement from `resolve(null)` to `resolve(this.aadharValues)` but it still doesn't work. What am i doing wrong here?

Comment: You need to resolve in the same scope as your `subscribe`, so do it directly after your for loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are calling `resolve(null);` without waiting for `this.http.put(...)` to finish. It might all work if you resolve the promise after the for loop finishes.